# Question about balancing color palettes

Tags: color-theory, color-reproduction

I am currently learning color theory in depth, and I have trouble figuring out how to balance a color palette and how chroma plays a role in it.

I have read an article that the following image (the one on the bottom) looks balanced because the colors have the same chroma. I tried desaturating the colors and turning the image in grayscale in order to grasp the concept of chroma.

However, it appears that they indeed do not have the same chroma.

My question is: Why the bottom palette looks more balanced than the top one, even though the top one has the exact same brightness and saturation values.

I think it may be something with color perception or that the blue seems the main color and the others are little bit desaturated on purpose, but I cannot fully grasp it.

Any ideas/tips on how to improve my palettes?

[image]

Original image:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Colour balance within themes/groups of colours is entirely subjective. In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with either of these.  Don't stress so much. There is no right or wrong when it comes to balancing colours. Choose whichever you like best.

Comment: Color theory is more concerned about color mixing than actual colors your mixing space generates. The immediate problem is that the color wheels differ from space to space. So its not absolute. Its not a science, that is reserved for color science.